# Generic implementation, a question about simplifying the code

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Have this straightforward sample implementation:

```
    public abstract class IdProperty<ID>
    {
        public ID Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassOfAbstract : IdProperty<int> { }

    public T TestObject<T, ID>() where T : IdProperty<ID>
    {
        T item = default(T);
        //some logic
        return item;
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        var item = TestObject<ClassOfAbstract, int>();
    }
```

I wonder if it is possible to simplify this.

Since the generic type of IdProperty<**int**> is already known (it is given in class ClassOfAbstract), it should not be necessary to add the information again in TestObject<T, **ID**>.

With a minor change, the code would then look like this:

```
    //NO CHANGE public abstract class IdProperty<ID>
    //NO CHANGE public class ClassOfAbstract : IdProperty<int> { }

    public T TestObject<T>() where T : IdProperty<???>
    {
        T item = default(T);
        //some logic
        return item;
    }
    [Test]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        var item = TestObject<ClassOfAbstract>();
    }
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: You appear to have prefixed the name of your abstract class with an "I", which is only a convention for interfaces. Also, implementation is something you do with interfaces too, while you inherit classes. You might use the term "implement" for the abstract methods that you override.

Comment: True, it was an interface to begin with - minor error I would say :-)

Comment: Either you want that method to only work for IDs of type `int`, in which case you would replace `???` with `int`, or you want it to work for any type, in which case you need your original code.

Comment: These kinds of interfaces are rarely worth it compared to passing a `Func<T, TValue>` delegate that encapsulates the property access (`o => o.Id`). Going one step further, if you're working by convention you could consider leaving out the delegate altogether (or at least making it optional) and reflecting over the `Id` property to establish the delegate (this is not slow if cached). Going even further, if you're rolling your own entity classes for an ORM this is even less worth it.

Comment: All comments are appreciated, but I just want to know if the simplification is possible or not as it seems redundant to have to give the type twice.

Comment: Is `TestObject()` inside a class? Can this class accept any generic types?

Comment: Only types of IdProperty, if I understand you right - also remember that this is just a TEST, it may never hit running code in any form at all.